# How to do "And" queries using mongo db c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to run a query that is and of two independent queries but it seems to be producing no result.Here is the query..

```
 var query = Query.And(Query<Account>.EQ(a => a.UserName, userName), 
                  Query<Account>.EQ(a=> a.Password,password));

 var account = mongoAccount.FindOne(query);
```

The account comes as null.What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

The question can also be rephrased as what is the c# equivalent of mongoDb and.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = Query.And(Query<Account>.EQ(a => a.UserName, userName), 
                Query<Account>.EQ(a => a.Password, password));

var account = mongoAccount.FindOne(query);
```

**ADDED**

Just to be on safe side, check if mongoAccount contains the combination of userName and password for some Account. Otherwise you have done it correctly, it should work.

Comment: This won't compile. Eq expects two parameters what to compare and  what to compare against seperated by a comma.Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: Okay I was entering the wrong password.I feel stupid.Thanks for the help though :)